# getting default values from Battery maneger intent

Tags: android, android-intent, batterylevel

i am trying to monitor my battery state but i keep getting back default values from the listener, this is my receiver class:

```
public class BatteryIndicatorListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("battery status", "changed");

    int status = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
    boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||   status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;
    int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
    int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

    int chargePlug = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
    boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

    Log.d("battery status", "chargeplug: "+chargePlug);
   Log.d("battery status", "status: "+status);
   Log.d("battery status", "is charging: "+isCharging);
   Log.d("battery status", "usb charging: "+usbCharge);
   Log.d("battery status", "ac charging: "+acCharge);
  Log.d("battery status", "level: "+level);
   Log.d("battery status", "scale: "+scale);
```

and here are my logcat outputs:

```
03-18 10:44:50.806: D/battery status(7855): changed
03-18 10:44:50.806: D/battery status(7855): chargeplug: -1
03-18 10:44:50.806: D/battery status(7855): status: -1
03-18 10:44:50.806: D/battery status(7855): is charging: false
03-18 10:44:50.806: D/battery status(7855): usb charging: false
03-18 10:44:50.806: D/battery status(7855): ac charging: false
03-18 10:44:50.806: D/battery status(7855): level: -1
03-18 10:44:50.806: D/battery status(7855): scale: -1
```

my manifest has this this:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY"/>



<receiver android:name="com.zivkesten.find_a_place.control.service.BatteryIndicatorListener" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_LOW"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
```